# how to integrate vserv ads sdk to windows phone 8 application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sdk, ads

I have developed a windows phone 8 application. Now I want to display vserv ads to my application.
I have added the sdk to my application and also applied code to show ads:

```
public MainPage()   
   {   
        InitializeComponent();   
        VservAdControl VMB = VservAdControl.Instance;    
        VMB.DisplayAd(zoneID, LayoutRoot);        
        VMB.VservAdClosed += new EventHandler(VACCallback_OnVservAdClosing);
        VMB.VservAdNoFill += new EventHandler(VACCallback_OnVservAdNoFill);   
    }   

void VACCallback_OnVservAdClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {   
        MessageBox.Show("Ad close by user.");   
    }   
void VACCallback_OnVservAdNoFill(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {    
        if (adGrid != null)    
            adGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;   
    }
```

But after closing the ad the application page goes blank, all content, application bar automatically goes blank. After using back arrow that quits my application, i try to relaunch my application but application stuck at the splash screen on the emulator.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project, as an extra measure, try restarting the emulator too.

Comment: I restarted the emulator many times but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap ad control inside a grid. Ad control could have manipulated the grid
I encountered the same issue and they have updated their SDK several times. If you provide the stacktrace they will provide you a fix.

Apart from what you have seen, there are other issues with the SDK. I integrated it few weeks back. So issues could have been resolved after that.

1. Memory leak. Click the ad or navigate back and forth - you will see the memory ever growing. This is because of events not being detached (withing SDK). I was consistently able to see my app crash in 512 MB emulator when banner ad is loaded (after 4 - 5 times). They could have used weak listeners. You might need to tweak a lot to overcome this issue (In multi page app)
2. RequestAdCallback throws null pointer exception sometimes crashing
   the app. When people use app, they will navigate fast - forcing the
   webbrowser to unload. All callbacks should be null pointer exception
   free. Make sure that you handle unhandled exception globally otherwise app will not pass certification
3. It reads WMAppManifest.xml as text not as XML. So I had App element commented in first line before the actual one. It picked title from commented XML element
4. Application bar is manipulated in many events in the SDK. So you have to make sure that app bar is built dynamically. Test all navigation paths.
5. SDK assumes user will click the left arrow button which fires ad closing event. Try pressing phone back button instead. The app bar still disappears
6. SDK documentation requests app to demand ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE capability. I don't see a reason to request this capability but I didn't add this

I have emailed them all these details. May be their latest SDK could have resolved these issues. But please do thorough testing after integration.

Comment: Memory leak is the reason behind one of my problem. When I try to relaunch my application on 512 MB emulator, application stuck at the splash screen. That's why my app was rejected from certification process. How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to load applicationbar using code

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
        ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = false;

        // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarIconButton button1 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
        button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/sms.png", UriKind.Relative);
        button1.Text = "sms";
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button1);

    }
```

and then in VACCallback_OnVservAdClosing event handler call the function
    BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()

Comment: this only helps to retain the ApplicationBar of the app, still can't able to retain other content including whole grid content or application title, etc.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly is the problem but, the issue I am currently having is that once ad is clicked and then closed.... and then if you try to open ShareStatusTask or SmsComposeTask and return back to application , "Application_UnhandledException" is thrown and gets crashed. I had mailed them about this, lets see if they come up with any solution.

Comment: I dont know if they have updated the sdk on their website, but they have replied me with the modified sdk and it fixed the problem, if you want I can mail it to you.

Comment: Yes the SDK was updated. Please drop an email to developersupport@vserv.mobi

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following link, 
[where to add application id and adUnitiD while integrating vserv ads sdk to windows phone 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961712/where-to-add-application-id-and-adunitid-while-integrating-vserv-ads-sdk-to-wind), which is related to your question.