# where to add application id and adUnitiD while integrating vserv ads sdk to windows phone 8 application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sdk, ads

I have added this code in my app to get vserv ads and i have generated Ad unit id and application id as well.

```
VservAdControl VMB = VservAdControl.Instance;

public MainPage()   
   {   
        InitializeComponent();   

        VMB.DisplayAd(zoneID, LayoutRoot);        
        VMB.VservAdClosed += new EventHandler(VACCallback_OnVservAdClosing);
        VMB.VservAdNoFill += new EventHandler(VACCallback_OnVservAdNoFill);   
    }   

void VACCallback_OnVservAdClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {   
        MessageBox.Show("Ad close by user.");   
    }   
void VACCallback_OnVservAdNoFill(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {    
        if (adGrid != null)    
            adGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;   
    }
```

But where to add these two ids in my code to request the ads ?? Is there any property of VservAdControl Instance i need to set ??

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use test id's instead of the ID you have. Some time there are no ads available at the moment of testing. They may make you believe that you are doing something wrong even when you are not.

here are the test ids. Test on these first.

Billboard Test ZoneID: 8063

Banner Test ZoneID: 20846

Source: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UPyMmCD3GApJ-GauTKo53hjtTcnugF4YuUSA5d28GrI/edit?pli=1#

Answer (score 0):

To use Banner add add the id VMB.RenderAd(id,adGrid) and if you want billboard add( full screen ads) VMB.DisplayAd(id,adgrid)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace your code where ever ZoneID is mentioned

for Interstitials it will be

```
VMB.DisplayAd(zoneID, LayoutRoot);
```

and for banners it will be

```
RenderAd(int zoneId, grid);
```